# Use case class field name as data frame column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let's say I have this case class:

```scala
case class A(id: String)
```

And I have a data frame - `df`.

I want to select only the `id` column from `df`, but I don't want to use strings.

So instead of doing:

```scala
df.select($"id")
```

I want to do something like:

```scala
df.select(nameof(A.id))
```

Is there any way I can do this in scala?

Comment: You can only use `A.id` when you have `A` as `StructType` column in the dataframe having `id` field.

Comment: What is your finish goal? What are you want to achieve? If you need to work with `DataFame` as a `Dataset[A]` you can do it just using `as` function on DataFrame API: `df.as[A]`